# Exception when trying to deserialize the JSON object

Tags: .net, json

I am trying to deserialiaze a json object but on line `ser.WriteObject(ms, inpJsonObj);` an exception is thrown

Edit:
As suggested I created a new memory stream and copied the modified object in the new stream . However the "Out" string still is blank !

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestJSON));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inpStr));
            ms.Position = 0;
            TestJSON obj = (TestJSON)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            obj.Var11 = 99;
            obj.Var21 = 199;


            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(ms1, obj);

            ms1.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms1);
            Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
            ms1.Close();
            ms.Close();
```

Comment: @dystroy I get "Memory Stream is not expandable"

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exception details I can only guess, but looks like the problem is that you are creating an instance of the [non-resizable memory stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) and trying to write an updated object into it - probably the result of the serialization is larger than the original string and thus stream cannot accept it.

Comment: I get "Memory Stream is not expandable"

Comment: So looks like I was right - you need to either create an expandable memory stream or write an updated object to another memory stream instance.

Comment: I dont know how to create an expandable memory stream  so I create a new one ..but  now its not reflecting the new values that I assign to the object